# Bootstrap DateTimePicker for Arabic Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Bootstrap Datetimepickers I need to get only the date in the datepicker value.

But in the Arabic calendar when I am trying to replace DateTimePicker with DatePicker the calendar popup does not work

```
$(function () {
  $('#txtIssueDate').datetimepicker();   
  $('#txtEshtablishedDate').datetimepicker(); // Umm ALqura Calendar 
  $('#txtExpiryDateHijri').datetimepicker({ locale: { calender: 'ummalqura', lang: 'ar' } });
  $('#txtEshtablishedDateHijri').datetimepicker({ locale: { calender: 'ummalqura', lang: 'ar' } });
  $('#txtCRIssueDateHijri').datetimepicker({ locale: { calender: 'ummalqura', lang: 'ar' } }); 
});
```

Note - I have a requirement of displaying only the date in Arabic(not date n time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the format below will disable the time picker. Keep other options of yours unchanged

```
$('#txtExpiryDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reponse.Its working with the above mentioned but not with Locale.I mean Arabic calendar.                 $('#txtEshtablishedDateHijri').datetimepicker({
                    locale: { calender: 'ummalqura', lang: 'ar' }

Comment: The calendar does not support arabic locale by default. Have you made sure to follow documentation in supporting other locale?

Comment: The above datepickers( hijri & gregorian) which i have got in their respective textboxes.There is a scenario i which if the user selects gragorain date,then the respective hijri date should be reflected in the respective textbox.

Comment: or if the user selects Hijri Date then the respective gregorian date should be reflected in the respective textboxes.